# Box2d ContactListener function. Problem calling a function on the collided objects

Tags: c++, box2d

I created a ContactListener class which derives from b2ContactListener. I am following the excellent tutorials found here: https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks
Collisions are detected and report output (std::cout lines) states the correct names for the object (Note that I use the Fixture's Userdata to see my custome FixtureUserData struct, which holds a name for each type of block or other collide-able game object).

But when I try to get the Body UserData (which here, I set it as a pointer to the block class itself ie. UserData('this')).

I've read the linked tutorial, and others dozens of times but I cannot adapt it to my code. To me, it looks almost exactlyh the same as his example, just that he only cares if both objects are 'balls' but I need to check is 'mario's top collider' and 'block' fixture collisions.

Somehow when I pass the pointer in the Body UserData (rather than my own struct), it is lost or something, because I call the block::Hit() and it seems to do nothing to the block in question. However if you put a log output command in there then it does print. It gets wierder though as for example if I print the sprite width (should be 16) it will give random numbers in the millions (pos/neg), each time I compile they are different.

I really guess I have missed an asterisk somewhere or something like this but I've spent hours trying different things and it really looks correct to me so I don't know how to get past this problem.

Here is the relevant code (i think) (note: I know ContactListener is working as I tested with log commands eg I get string in BeginContact saying Mario hit Block):

```
 void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
FixtureUserData* fdA = (FixtureUserData*)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetUserData();
FixtureUserData* fdB = (FixtureUserData*)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetUserData();

void* udA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
void* udB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();



if (fdA != nullptr && fdB != nullptr && udA != nullptr && udB != nullptr)
{
    std::string a = fdA->friendlyName;
    std::string b = fdB->friendlyName;
    if (a == Constants::MARIO_TOP_SENSOR_FIXTUREDATA_NAME && 
        b == Constants::BLOCK_FIXTUREDATA_NAME)
    {
        HandleBlockContact(static_cast<Block*>(udB));
    }
    else if (a == Constants::BLOCK_FIXTUREDATA_NAME && 
             b == Constants::MARIO_TOP_SENSOR_FIXTUREDATA_NAME)
    {
        HandleBlockContact(static_cast<Block*>(udA));
    }
}
}

void ContactListener::HandleBlockContact(Block* block)
{
block->hit();
}
```

Block.cpp:

```
void Block::start(BlockType type, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, sf::Texture& texture, unsigned int image_x, unsigned int image_y, b2World* world)
{
float hx = width / 2.f;
float hy = height / 2.f;
worldPtr = world;

sprite.setTexture(texture);
sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(image_x, image_y, width, height));
sprite.setOrigin(hx, hy);
sprite.setPosition(x, y);
startPosition = sprite.getPosition();

bodyDef.position.Set(x, y);
bodyPtr = worldPtr->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
bodyPtr->SetUserData((void*)this); // <--- I guess this is wrong. Also compiles if I dont cast it. Tried both already

box.SetAsBox(hx, hy);


mainFixture.shape = &box;


blockType = type;
fixtureData_main = new FixtureUserData; fixtureData_main = new FixtureUserData;
fixtureData_main->friendlyName = Constants::BLOCK_FIXTUREDATA_NAME;
mainFixture.userData = fixtureData_main;
bodyPtr->CreateFixture(&mainFixture);

 }

void Block::hit()
{
std::cout << "block x: " << sprite.getPosition().x << std::endl;
std::cout << "block y: " << sprite.getPosition().y << std::endl;
sprite.setColor(sf::Color::Blue); // <--- IT DOESN'T CHANGE COLOR WHEN FUNCTION IS CALLED.
}
```

Furthermore, the output results from the above code Block::Hit() function, as stated, is wierd long numbers. But interestingly the numbers match depending on which sprite is used for the block. So the number must relate to something about the actual texture/sprite location in memory maybe? So all red blocks give some long number, then the '?' Blocks all give some other long number.

To put my question simply, why does the sprite for the block mario hits not change color when i call the function?

---

(Github repo of project is [here](https://github.com/Golden-Nuggs/Mario/tree/3f100a97acd85d60f640ab8fd09289edb1c59f41)).

Comment: Generally, if you can, in such "complex" situations, you could post a link to a github repo so that we can try and investigate a bit further. Here, it's not clear how your sprites are used. Personally, I would have created the sprite on the heap to make sure I never copy them and modify the wrong instance.

Comment: OK I will start creating github repos with projects i intend to see through to completion (such as this one) thanks. When you say 'on the heap' do you mean I should create it using the 'new' keyword when i instantiate it?

Comment: but by the way, i also tried adding velocity and moving position of the b2bodty (and doing nothing to the sprite), but this also didnt work and in fact I think gave a nullptr style crash error that I didnt fully understand ( I guess its using a copy, which ofc didnt have a b2body instantiated on it)

Comment: I made the member in Block a sf::sprite* and i put in constructor sprite = new sf::Sprite . Does this mean i created it on heap now? (sorry I have often heard it but not known its meaning). Lol after making that change, the game crashes when collide with Block.... which i guess i expected actually. Still can't solve why its not referencing the actual block that is in UserData

Comment: Yes, when you use new, It's created on the heap. The next thing that you could do is make your block non-copyable by deleting the copy ctor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: I'm going afk now, will be able to help further tomorrow if it's not solved.

Comment: for what its worth I added a github repo link to the top of my question. Thanks as always for your time.

Comment: You store your Block objects in an `std::vector<Block>` but don't properly implement move or copy operations for your block object, which means that when the vector reallocates memory (and your initial block instances goes out of scope) during initialization, stuff happens extremely incorrectly. Can you check if the issue fixes itself if you start storing `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Block>>`, or if you implement the correct move & copy operations?

Comment: thanks for the advice about my use of pointers and vectors being wrong. I think i've now made it vector<unique_ptr<Block>> using make_unique. But the game still doesnt work. I need to learn now about this implementing of move and copy operations. One thing I have noticed since my last message was I checked the 'bodyPtr->GetUserData for every element of my "all_blocks" vector from inside LevelManager, every result is the same for all blocks (I guess i didn't make the unique_ptr properly after all.).

Comment: dudes i freckin' love you all !! I got it to work but adding a move operation to the Block class, then changing my vector back to just be a vector of Block* and then each block I instantiated with 'new' keyword. I will post it as an answer soon so others can see.